# Derivative relation between two equal functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

I am stuck with the following problem. Suppose $g: \Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ is $C^1$. $f(x,y)=g(x^2+y^2)$. I need to show that $xf_y=yf_x$

My attempt was:

$f_x=g_x \cdot 2x$ (1) and $f_y=g_y\cdot 2y$ (2)

Multiplying (1) by y and (2) by x, I get
$yf_x=g_x \cdot2xy$ and $xf_y=g_y\cdot 2xy$

So the only thing now I need to show is that $g_x=g_y$ Does $C^1$ satisfy that condition? If not, how can I prove that? A good hint would be appreciated. I would be very thankful :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with $g_x$? If you can answer this question, I think you'll see the answer.

Comment: By $g_x$ I mean the partial derivative of $g$ with respect to $x$

Comment: But $g$ is a one variable function. What do you mean with partial derivative of a one variable function?

Comment: Oh yeah, it is one variable function, so the partial derivative is the derivative itself. But does that imply anything?

Comment: I'm unable to tell if you really got what I mean. Replace $g$ with a concrete function, say $g=\sin$. What do you get for $f_x$?

Comment: it is always the same answer right? If you change the variables, then the derivative is always the same because it is one variable. I got it

Comment: As @GitGud says, you could try for example $g(t)=\sin(t)$, then $f(x,y)=\sin(x^2+y^2)$. Now $f_x$, $f_y$ and $g'$ exist, but $g_x$ or $g_y$ don't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the chain rule
$$f_x(x,y)=g'(x^2+y^2)\cdot (2x) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad y\cdot f_x(x,y)=g'(x^2+y^2)\cdot 2xy$$
$$f_y(x,y)=g'(x^2+y^2)\cdot (2y) \quad\Longrightarrow\quad x\cdot f_y(x,y)=g'(x^2+y^2)\cdot 2xy$$
And the equality follows.